# I have a question about an integral in Purcell's book on page 31

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

ok, the original text is \

> But Gauss's Law tell us that dE, the change in E through the thin slab, is just $\rho/ \epsilon_0 dx $,  Hence $\quad\rho dx $ in Eq.33 can be replaced by $\quad\epsilon_0 dE\quad$ and the intergral becomes
> \begin{equation*}
> F = \epsilon_0\int_{E_1}^{{E_2}}E dE = 2(E_2^2-E_!^2)/\epsilon_0  \tag{34}
> \end{equation*}
> since $E_2-E_1 = \sigma/\epsilon_0$, the result in Eq.34, after being fatored, can be expresser as
> \begin{equation}
> F=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0} (E_1 +E_2)\sigma \tag{35}
> \end{equation}

ok, so I have two questions about the previous test:  
first, shouldn't the integral of Eq.34 be solved as $\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}(E_2^2-E_1^2)$? 
second, if the eq.34 is correct, how should I derive the 35 equation? \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my copy (3rd Edition), that line is equation (1.48), and it reads

$$\frac{F}{A} = \int_{E_1}^{E_2} \epsilon_0 E dE = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}(E_2^2-E_1^2)$$

So yes, it appears that was a typo which has been corrected.  From there, you can use the fact that $\epsilon_0(E_2-E_1) = \sigma$, which appears a few lines above, to obtain the result that you want.

Comment: Just as I expected, thank you though, LOVE U!